# Java JDBC creates the database but will return false when creating a table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a database with java jdbc and create a table but the function will return false and the table won't be created. The program connects to the database so the connection isn't the problem

I am using 3 classes:

**BloodBank**:
It is the main class which establishes the connection to the database and creates an object containing mysql connection and then it is supposed to create a table

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class BloodBank {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        final String USER = "root";
        final String PASS = "root";

        
       ConnectionProvider connection=new ConnectionProvider(USER,PASS,"Donators");
       DonorTableImpl donor=new DonorTableImpl(connection.getMySQLConnection());
       donor.createTable();
    }
}
```

**ConnectionProvider**:
Connects to an existing database

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public final class ConnectionProvider {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String dbName;

    /**
     * @param username the username used to connect to the database
     * @param password the password used to connect to the database
     * @param dbName the name of the database to connect to
     */
    public ConnectionProvider (final String username, final String password, final String dbName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }

    /**
     * @return a Connection with the database specified in the class constructor
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the connection could not be establish
     */
    public Connection getMySQLConnection() {
        final String dbUri = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1";
        try {
            // Thanks to the JDBC DriverManager we can get a connection to the database
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUri, this.username, this.password);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not establish a connection with db", e);
        }
    }
}
```

**DonorTableImpl**:
Sends the queries. For now I have implemented only createTable() which is the one that's not working. The function returns false

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

public class DonorTableImpl implements DonorTable<Donor,Integer>{
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "donators";

    private final Connection connection;

    public DonorTableImpl(final Connection connection) {
        this.connection = Objects.requireNonNull(connection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean createTable() {
        // 1. Create the statement from the open connection inside a try-with-resources
        try (final Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement()) {
            // 2. Execute the statement with the given query
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME +
                    "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                    " first VARCHAR(255), " +
                    " last VARCHAR(255), " +
                    " age INTEGER, " +
                    " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Table created");
            return true;
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Table couldn't be created");
            // 3. Handle possible SQLExceptions
            return false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return TABLE_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dropTable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> findByPrimaryKey(Donor primaryKey) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(Integer value) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Integer updatedValue) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Donor primaryKey) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: A good first step would be to check what the `SQLException`'s message is.

Comment: Seems like the JDBC code is using MySQL. MySQL != Microsoft SQL Server, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72375700/edit) your question to correct the tags.

Comment: It is giving me "No database selected". I don't understand because in BloodBank i initialise the connection and use it in object donor

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided the name of the specific database that you want to connect to. For example check this postgresql example:
`.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"`

The testdb at the end denotes the logical name of the database that the programmer wants to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on ConnectionProvider class. The class connects to localhost but not to the database itself. So in url string I added dbName:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

/**
 * Expose a utility method to connect to a MySQL database
 */
public final class ConnectionProvider {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final String dbName;

    /**
     * @param username the username used to connect to the database
     * @param password the password used to connect to the database
     * @param dbName the name of the database to connect to
     */
    public ConnectionProvider (final String username, final String password, final String dbName) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.dbName = dbName;
    }

    /**
     * @return a Connection with the database specified in the class constructor
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the connection could not be establish
     */
    public Connection getMySQLConnection() {
        final String dbUri = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/"+dbName;
        try {
            // Thanks to the JDBC DriverManager we can get a connection to the database
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUri, this.username, this.password);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not establish a connection with db", e);
        }
    }
}
```